# How to set the EType in Ecore Modeling Project?

Tags: eclipse, ecore

I would like to create a model using Eclipse and Ecore Modeling Project and I cannot set the EType of an attribute. I can only set it manually by typing the Type behind the attribute name. Where can I find the dropdown or something else.
I try to follow this tutorial: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html

Here's also a screenshot of my properties tab in Eclipse
[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

the Etype can be changed in the semantic tab